# Cannot change priority for a WatiN test VS 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, watin

I get the error: "The method or operation is not implemented" every time I change the priority of a test under properties. What's going on? And oh its VS 2008 for those who know that is. I need to force some order to replicate something.

CORRECTION: This is not NUnit, it's WatiN.Core 2.1 (Integration tests). Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: You should probably post some code or a stack trace with this, y'know, so people can help?

Comment: Correction this is not NUnit, it's WatiN.Core 2.1 (Integration tests). Sorry about the confusion. I think it's not in the code since it happens on any test, can't set the description either.